# Typescript - Get property of name with string, as generic type

Tags: typescript

I butchered the title, not sure the technical term for what I want to do. Type constraints are a bit mind boggling to me at the moment as I learn them in both F# and Typescript simultaneously.

I have a variable of interface state that holds lists of every type of data needed on the page

```
interface state{
    clients: clients[]
    appointments: appointments[]
    ...
}

const ApplicationState : state = {...}
```

I want a generic function that can be used to get a specific client, appointment, whatever by id.

So something that looks like

```
getData('clients', 2)
```

I have started by defining a type of allowed properties (if this can be done a better way let me know).

`type entity = "clients" | "appointments"`

But would I then be able to get the property of `ApplicationState`?

So the `getData` function could look something like this?

```
const getData = (foo: entity, id: number) => {
    ApplicationState.magicallyGetPropertyByName.filter(entity => entity.id = foo.id)
}
```

Is this possible while keeping type inference?

Thank you

Comment: pls share reproducible example. Where did you get `entity` type ? SHould `magicallyGetPropertyByName` be computed from arguments?

Comment: Well I’m not sure how to produce it. Entity type is defined as above. And yes, infer which property to load form the argument that is passed.

Comment: I have overlooked `entity`. My bad

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here, is that you are not allowed to call `filter` on a union like this:

```js
type Clients = {
  tag: 'Clients'
  id: number
}

type Appointments = {
  tag: 'Appointments'
  id: number
}

declare const test: Clients[] | Appointments[]

test.filter(elem => elem)
```

Please see  [issues/7294](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294) and  [issues/13097](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13097)

However, there is a workaround:

```js
type Clients = {
  tag: 'Clients'
  id: number
}

type Appointments = {
  tag: 'Appointments'
  id: number
}

type State = {
  clients: Clients[]
  appointments: Appointments[]
}

type Entity = keyof State;

declare const ApplicationState: State

const withState = <
  S extends Record<string, { id: number }[]>
>(state: S) =>
  <E extends keyof S>(prop: E, id: number) =>
    state[prop].filter(entity => entity.id === id)

const getData = withState(ApplicationState);

getData('clients', 2)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSwgO2AZygXigbwFBRTACGA5gFxQDk8SqaVBUCAJpcgK4C2ARhAE54AvnjyhIUAIJgwAewSouKdFlxMSFatLkLgS%20o0Kt23PoJFjw0AMolg0bPkIBjRMrSVa7gNoBdJsQy8orulNrBej7%20FuLQAKKoCKCqANYQILIAZlC2xPYA3KIsEK7E-NDOsshowFIyiM55CFW59pStEKKV1bUA7kkAFh2qADxM1lAQAB72yCwYAEolsvwsIzX8CqQANLjMbFCcvAJQQn4AfHjnABQ1eRDtAJRYl4QjcZMzKPNQaRnZ1huYH4sjAlDiu2Mh1MAmemFehCgd3s3mBoN8ADpMgg4PZ%20NdlEkQC9JolQBjWFhMNhWI8ulUalBSBBgAARPLEVT9YBDOwQa7aBpNFp8x6FPDMtkc65UVx0dBUXYAJjpQA)
As you might have noticed, I have declared `State` as a `type` instead of `interface`. This is because `interfaces` are not indexed by the default. If you change it back to `interface`,`withState` will cause an error.

In fact, you don't need to know exact types of `clients` and `appointments`, you just have to make sure that all of these types have common property `id`.